# Alternative to updating SNS subscriptions using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

There's an *AWS CloudFormation* stack which defines an SNS topic and an SNS subscription. In another *Ansible* task, I want to update another subscription, but this isn't possible as SNS subscriptions can't be updated.

Using *Ansible* to perform *CloudFormation*. What are the alternatives?

1. Club *AWS CLI* with *Ansible* and then execute plays which contain *AWS CLI* content?
2. Create a custom module in *Ansible* using `boto`? But this would be difficult as I should store SNS ARN's and give those to the custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible v2.0 added support of an sns_topic module.  You can provide a name or ARN of an existing SNS topic to converge.  You also probably want to set purge_subscriptions to False so any existing subscriptions are not removed.

```
- name: Update SNS topic subscriptions
  sns_topic:
    name: "my-topic"
    purge_subscriptions: False
    subscriptions:
      - endpoint: "some-email@example.com"
        protocol: "email"
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/sns_topic_module.html